# Why is python3 is not working in command prompt when my python version is 3.9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, coding-style

While running the python file in cmd I have tried python filename and python filename. It works only with python filename. I have python version 3.9 and have added the path as well. I would therefore like to know what is causing the issue. Is it because I have two versions and version 2.7 is overruling version 3.9?

Comment: Run command ```py```. See which version pops up. The which you need should be added at the top

Comment: try ```which python``` to see which is the version the system you have is currently on

Comment: its working on 3.9

Answer (score 0):

command has been changed to py instead of python3